# In Dynamics AX, using the Business Connector, how do you call kernel functions?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, business-connector

I would like to know how to call kernel functions from AX using C# (.Net Business Connector).

Specifically, can you call methods like fieldName2Id, tableName2Id and curUserId?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I found some workarounds to calling kernel functions:**

### tableName2Id

(I was originally thinking of the `tablenum` method):

```
   //I used an extension method here  
   public static int GetTableId(this Axapta ax, string tableName)  
   {  
       return (int)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("Global", "tableName2Id", tableName);  
   }
```

### curUserId

```
    //Another extension method  
    public static string CurUserId(this Axapta ax)  
    {  
        return (ax.CallStaticClassMethod("xUserInfo", "find") as AxaptaRecord).get_Field("Id").ToString();  
    }
```

## fieldName2Id

(I was originally thinking of the `fieldnum` method)

```
    //Another extension method  
    public static int GetFieldId(this Axapta ax, string tableName, string fieldName)  
    {  
        AxaptaObject dictionary = ax.CreateAxaptaObject("Dictionary");  
        int fieldId = 0;  
        if (ax.TableExists(tableName))  
        {  
            int tableId = ax.GetTableId(tableName);  
            AxaptaObject dictTable = (AxaptaObject)dictionary.Call("tableObject", tableId);  
            fieldId = (int)dictTable.Call("fieldName2Id", fieldName);  
        }  
        return fieldId;  
    }
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use:

```
Dictionary  dictionary = new Dictionary();
;
dictionary.tableName2Id(...);
```

Comment: Add some description